# Trying to implement DFA but the code is generating errors

Tags: python, dfa

**Code:-**

```
#Shortest DFA implementation in Python
S,D,F=input()
s=1
for c in S:s=D[s,c]
print(["Not a chance!","Accepted!"][F&s>0])
```

**Input:-** 
Input is a triple of string S, a delta function D, and final state mask F. I number each state with a power of 2, so F is just the OR of each accepting state.  D is a map from (state,input char) -> state.

Example input (accepts all strings ending in b):

```
'abab',{(1,'a'):1,(1,'b'):2,(2,'a'):1,(2,'b'):2},2
```

**Output:-**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-506f09a31940> in <module>()
      1 #Shortest DFA implementation in Python
----> 2 S,D,F=input()
      3 s=1
      4 for c in S:s=D[s,c]
      5 print(["Not a chance!","Accepted!"][F&s>0])

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

Similarly, the following code is for implementing an NFA. But it is throwing a different kind of error, even after adding the eval(). The code is as follows:-

```
#Shortest NFA implementation
S,D,F=eval(input())
s=1
for c in S:
 t,s=s,0
 for a,b in D[c]:s|=t/a%2*b
print(["Not a chance!","Accepted!"][F&s>0])
```

**Input:-**
We number states as powers of 2 as before.  D is a map from input character to a list of transitions labelled by that character.

example input (accepts all strings ending in b):

```
'abab',{'a':[(1,1)],'b':[(1,1),(1,2)]},2
```

**The output obtained is:-**

```
'abab',{'a':[(1,1)],'b':[(1,1),(1,2)]},2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-7e5418d2d6fc> in <module>()
      4 for c in S:
      5  t,s=s,0
----> 6  for a,b in D[c]:s|=t/a%2*b
      7 print(["Not a chance!","Accepted!"][F&s>0])

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |=: 'int' and 'float'
```

Please tell me the necessary but minimal modifications required in the above codes for it to execute successfully and produce the desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is valid in Python 2, not in Python 3.  I suspect the code is actually designed for Python 2 when you are using Python 3.  [`input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) in Python 2 not only reads in a string from the input, but it also performs an [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) statement which means that it will take the string and convert it into Python syntax.  [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) in Python 3 returns a string of what you put in.  The `eval` is not performed anymore as you see in Python 2.  To mimic what you see in Python 2, you need to run `eval` on top of `input`:

```
In [1]: S,D,F = eval(input())
'abab',{(1,'a'):1,(1,'b'):2,(2,'a'):1,(2,'b'):2},2

In [2]: S
Out[2]: 'abab'

In [3]: D
Out[3]: {(1, 'a'): 1, (1, 'b'): 2, (2, 'a'): 1, (2, 'b'): 2}

In [4]: F
Out[4]: 2
```

## Edit

With your new code that you're running, the culprit is the division operation in the loop: `t/a`.  This returns a floating-point number by default whereas in Python 2, if `t` and `a` are both integers, it will return an integer.  You have to be careful running Python 2 code in a Python 3 environment.  Simply wrap `t/a` in an `int` call: `int(t/a)`.

```
In [7]: S,D,F=eval(input())
   ...: s=1
   ...: for c in S:
   ...:  t,s=s,0
   ...:  for a,b in D[c]:s|=int(t/a)%2*b
   ...: print(["Not a chance!","Accepted!"][F&s>0])
   ...:
'abab',{'a':[(1,1)],'b':[(1,1),(1,2)]},2
Accepted!
```

My final note to you is to be exceptionally careful running Python 2 code in a Python 3 environment.  If possible, run the code in the environment it's designed for.  If not, this useful comparison guide of idioms from Python 2 to Python 3 should help: http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html.  In particular:

- `input`: http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html#input
- ... and finally the division operator: http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html#division

Comment: #Shortest NFA implementation
S,D,F=eval(input())
s=1
for c in S:
 t,s=s,0
 for a,b in D[c]:s|=t/a%2*b
print(["Not a chance!","Accepted!"][F&s>0])

Comment: @AkashDas I ran this code and I got `Accepted!` as the output.

Comment: I made the eval() modification to the DFA program and it ran fine. The code I have commented is for implementing NFA. I have modified the question accordingly. I am using Python 3. I have mentioned the error obtained as well. Can you please take a look and tell me if you come up with something. Thanks!

Comment: `t/a` returns a floating-point number by default whereas in Python 2, if `t` and `a` are both integers, it will return an integer.  You have to be careful running Python 2 code in a Python 3 environment.  Simply wrap `t/a` in an `int` call: `int(t/a)`.  I'll edit my post.

Comment: Thank you so much. The codes executed like a breeze. I am a newbie to Python. Just been a week being 'Pythonic'. I am from C and Java background. And a tiny bit of R. And here I find a large syntactic and logical gap between Python 2 and Python 3. Most of the codes on the internet are meant for Python 2 while I am working on the latest Python 3. Could you just briefly point out the common things I need to take care of while porting things from Python 2 to Python 3

Comment: No problem.  This guide of Python 2 to Python 3 idioms will help: http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html.  For `input`: http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html#input and finally for division: http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html#division.  BTW, if you no longer need help, it's common practice to accept the answer to let people know you no longer need help in this matter: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.  Thanks and good luck!

Comment: Thanks a tonne for all your help.